# Google Map Javascript API stopped viewing?

Tags: javascript, maps

On my page http://kizzme.co.uk/contact.html the Google Maps API was viewing fine  and then stopped.

Unsure what it could be.. coding isn't my strongest point!

Many thanks in advance!

Kizz

Answer (score 0):

can you see this script

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

in your code ??

maybe you delete it

Comment: Do you mean the

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" /></script>

If so I deleted it and it didn't work